# How do install wamp server 0

Tags: wampserver

When I finish install then it show

C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR110.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.

But recently I download MSVCR110.dll and I send it  C:\Windows\system32 and restart computer. But when I run Wamp server then it is also show this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to install WAMPServer 2.5 on a Windows XP system.

I am afraid that will not work as Apache/PHP & MySQL in that version are all compiled with MSCV11 (VC2012), and unfortunately the MSCV11 runtime will not run on Windows XP. This is a Microsoft thing and not a WAMPServer problem.

Your best bet is to install WampServer 2.2e as Apache/PHP & MySQL were all compiled with an ealier version of the compiler and that runtime will work on XP.